# Python importing module that imports another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following document structure:

```
root
  |src
    |__init__.py
    |util.py
    |mymodule.py
  |__init__.py
  |test.py
```

Both **init**.py are empty

In util.py I have a series of utility functions, for example a(), b(), c().

In mymodule.py I have:

```
from util import a, b, c

def somefunc():
    # some stuff
    a()
    # more stuff
```

In test.py I have:

```
from src.mymodule import somefunc
```

I would like to be able to reference these modules outside of src, but I am getting the error "error in mymodule.py from util import a, b, c, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to import utils using the module path like: `from src.util import a, b, c` or `from root.src.util import a, b, c` depending on where you plan to run/import your code from, the latter being for if you run/import  your code from the folder containing root

Comment: It depends where you're calling it from! if your goal is to import the root module, such as from the folder containing root, my suggestion works. So if you run your tests from outside of root it will import ok.

Comment: My goal is to call it from within root, however I tried calling from folder containing root, and I am still getting "error in mymodule.py from util import a, b, c, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'"

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood, amending my answer

Comment: No worries! I appreciate the help